# How do we manage SFTP connected hosts to an EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, restore

We may terminate our EC2 instances as per our requirements. If we do so, what is the fate of the SFTP connected downstream or upstream application hosts? Is there a backup strategy for it to restore the connection with a new EC2 instance created.?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are talking about.  Anything connected when an SFTP service or the machine it's running on is terminated will lose the connection and the client will have to manage reconnecting.  SFTP has no mechanism for migrating an established connection -- but then again, an SFTP client should disconnect as soon as it has transferred whatever it needed to transfer.  Idle SFTP connections are not typically used, and it's not clear why you'd terminate an active SFTP server.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I got the answer from it.  It was my doubt, just in case if we terminate an instance for any particular reason.. what would be the behavior of the existing active SFTP servers. How can I restore them on my new EC2 instance ?  But now I got the answer, @twg also helped to surge on ElasticIP

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly for some reason you leave open SFTP connections to your EC2 instance. The best way to instantiate the connection again when you take down an EC2 and bring up another one is to use ElasticIP. In this way the IP remains the same and I assume the rest of the parameters needed for connection you will just duplicate on the new EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you so much @twg .. got it, this is the best answer. BTW that was an interview question asked at Verizon.